# Spring auto load changes in jsp without compiling again

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp, spring-mvc

I come today with a simple question. Is there any plugin I can use in spring so everytime I make changes in one of my .jsp files, it makes a fast re-compiling instead of having to stop the project and compile it all over again?

For references I'm working on Spring Tool Suite and my project uses Maven, I've read about Spring Loaded and used the following code to implement it, but I just can't make it work.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Can anyone give me any advice about it, or if there's really a way to do this?

Comment: This is a feature of the JSP spec since the 0.9x days. That said, you need to deploy your jsp change into the web container. In eclipse with the tomcat plugin, this is done by simply saving the JSP file and reloading your browser.